# hashSet is including duplicates

Tags: javascript

This code is supposed to concat two elements inside of an Array without duplicating.
The data.CamData contains multiple objects, each object has a CamID, Status, and other data.
each (e) looks like this `{Date: 1656533249379, State: 0}`

```
    for (let i = 0; i < data.CamData.length; i++) {
        let hashSet = new Set();
        data.CamData[i].Events.forEach((e) => hashSet.add(e));
        state.camData[i].Events.forEach((e) => hashSet.add(e));
        data.CamData[i].Events = Array.from(hashSet);
      }
```

However, this code is just concatenating the two without getting rid of duplicates

I believe this is because even though the objects contain similar data they are the different objects. is there any other solution to this?

Comment: Not sure how to fix that but I believe this is caused by sets not deep comparing the objects. Instead, objects are likely to be compared by reference which are probably different here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Map or Object, you need to pick a key from your object, for instance 'Date' and set value by key

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.CamData.length; i++) {
        let hashMap = new Map();
        data.CamData[i].Events.forEach((e) => hashMap.set(e.Date, e));
        state.camData[i].Events.forEach((e) => hashMap.set(e.Date,e));
        data.CamData[i].Events = Array.from(hashMap.values());
      }
```

Hope this helps.